# Combining tests: Maximum test statistic method but one test is a permutation test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, permutation-test, combining-p-values

I want to combine two tests $A,B$ for the same null and alternative hypotheses. The motivation is that it has been shown that test $A$ has higher power in some situations whereas test $B$ has higher power in others.

One approach that has been used in this kind of scenario and which also seems appealing to me is to the maximum test approach, which works as follows. Let $T_A(x)$, and $T_B(x)$ be the test statistics of the two tests. The combined test then uses $max(|T_A(x)|,|T_B(x)|)$ as test statistic. The distribution under the null-hypothesis is approximated using a permutation approach.

However, this approach requires that the test statistics are properly standardized. In my case, however, one of the tests let's say $B$ has a rather obscure test statistic with unknown sampling distribution. Indeed, it's $p$-value is calculated via the permutation approach. So. it's unclear to me how to standardize in this case.

One potential remedy would be to use the minimum of the $p$-values as test statistic instead of the maximum of the standardized test statistics, which is actually equivalent. Note that this approach treats the $p$-values as test statistic. The final p-value that you report is actually obtained via the permutation approach again. However, this would imply some kind of nested permutation testing. First one permutes to get one $p$-value for test $B$ and then one permutes to get the $p$-value for the minimum test, which seems a bit stupid.

Comment: Why not just admit that you're P-hacking and use the smaller of the two P-values?

Comment: That's not p-hacking. The type I error rate of the full procedure is exactly the significance level $\alpha$ (assuming that both A, and B are exact). It's essentially Bonferroni correcting but estimating the dependency between the two tests using the permutation distribution.

Comment: Combining $p$-values using the minimum is known as Tippett's method but it is for independent values and although I do not fully grasp your situation I suspect that is not what you have here.

Comment: I doubt that this kind of hybrid test is appropriate, but it it were, taking the minimum P-value would solve your problem. Both P-values are on the same 0-to-1 scale, while you say your test statistics are not directly comparable.// I'm a fan of permutation tests and would be interested to know how yours differs essentially from your test using a known null distribution.